# Generating MDX (embeded in SQL) code using python

Tags: python, sql, dynamic, mdx

I am trying to generate SQL code (that has mdx embedded).
What I came up with till now is writing a function that I can change inputs from like the following:

```
def get_mdx(user
            , sqlhost = 'SQLBOADHOC'
            , Start_Year = 2018
            , End_Year = 2019
            , columns = 'All'):

    """This function pulls mdx data using an mdx code embedded in a SQL query
    -------
    Params:
    sql_user = Your company user ID
    sql_host = The host server usually it is 'SQLBOADHOC'
    Start_Year = 2018 for example
    End_Year = 2019 for example
    Columns: the columns retrieved

    ------
    returns:
    df = a dataframe with the data pulled
    """
    sql = f"""
    Select
    "[Time].[Date].[Date].[MEMBER_CAPTION]",
    convert(float,"[Measures].[Allowance]") as Allowances
    from openquery
    (DASHLB_CAP_Reporting, '
    With
    Member [Measures].[Allowance] AS IIF(Cstr([Measures].[Allowances])="1.#INF", null, [Measures].[Allowances])
        Select  {{
        [Measures].[Allowance]
        }} on 0,
        NON EMPTY{{crossjoin(
        [Subentity].[subentity],
        [Time].[Date].[Date]
        )}}    on 1
        from
        [Category and Promotions Cube]
        where (
        [Store].[Store by Brand].[Brand].&[1],
        {{[Time].[Time Filter By Month].[Year].&[{Start_Year}],[Time].[Time Filter By Month].[Year].&[{End_Year}]}}
    )')

    """
    sql_user = f"""company\\{user}"""
    sql_host = sqlhost
    sql_db = ''
    sql_conn = sql_util(sql_user, sql_host, sql_db, is_user=True)
    df_sql = sql_conn.pull(sql)
    if columns.isdigit:
        df_sql = f"""df_sql.iloc[:{columns}]"""
    else:
        df_sql = df_sql.iloc[:]
```

Now my question is as follows, suppose i wanna add a new column to my table such as ConversionRate I would have to add few sentences to the code and it would become the following:

```
mdx_columns= {"Allowances_dic" : {"place1" : f"""convert(float,"[Measures].[Allowance]") as Allowances,""",
"place2" : f""" Member [Measures].[Allowance] AS IIF(Cstr([Measures].[Allowances])="1.#INF", null, [Measures].[Allowances])""",
"place3" : f""" [Measures].[Allowance] """} }

mdx_base = f"""
Select
{place1}
"[Time].[Date].[Date].[MEMBER_CAPTION]" as Dates,

from openquery
(DASHLB_CAP_Reporting, '
With 
{place2}
    Select  {{
    {place3}
    }} on 0,
    NON EMPTY{{crossjoin(
    [Subentity].[subentity].&[2],
    [Time].[Date].[Date],
    )}}    on 1
    from
    [Category and Promotions Cube]
    where (
    {place4}
    [Store].[Store by Brand].[Brand].&[1],
    [Subentity].[Subentity Filter].[Subentity].&[2],
    {{[Time].[Time Filter By Month].[Year].&[2018],
     [Time].[Time Filter By Month].[Year].&[2019]}}
)')


"""
```

So my question is there an elegant way to always modify my main query whenever i add a new columns to it? or how do i build my query in blocks ?

Sorry for the long post and thank you so much for your help! I am still new to python and an Intern so im doing my best to learn fast!

Comment: so do you want to know how to add another column in the MDX query?

Comment: @MoazRub thank you for your question, I am trying to build a dynamic sql query. In the sense that when i add a new column lets say in the function 2 new lines in the code are generated so i want to ask how can i make this? So how can i add several line in the code in different places when the user adds new columns

Comment: Ok, so i think you want to know how to add columns in MDX, so that your your dynamic SQL query can emit the right MDX. Is that the case?

Comment: @MoazRub I want to know if there is a pattern, I would like to generate a function that takes in the column name and then pastes it in a string that would later on be used int he main query!

Comment: So you basicly want to emit MDX from the function.And you want to know what is the pattren to add a column in MDX query. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @MoazRub, thanks for your reply, So I did edit my post to include the general idea in the second coding block, basically I would have to have a nested dictionary with all the strings and then loop over them the generate a full mdx code, my question is could it be done in any other way? is there a pattern?